# Query problems with Hibernate (JPA) and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL as the database for Hibernate/JPA.  However, I get an error when executing a simple query.  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM UserProfile p ORDER BY :order
```

When I execute the query, I'll pass in a value like "lastLoginDate" for :order.  However, I get the following exception when trying to execute the query:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
  Position: 781
```

This query works just fine using MySQL as the database, but we'd like to move towards PostgreSQL.  My overall configuration and database connection is correct, as I see the tables being created properly.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there a configuration property I need to set?  Any help you can give would be MUCH appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you turn on SQL comments and add them to the post ?

Comment: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2007-02/msg00169.php

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/742896

Comment: give your code - what is `:order`, for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [postgreSQL group by different from mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769361/postgresql-group-by-different-from-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgresql prohibits that query because it is [ambiguous](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2007-02/msg00169.php):

> ```
> there's actually a definitional reason for it.  Consider
>
>         SELECT DISTINCT x FROM tab ORDER BY y;
>
> For any particular x-value in the table there might be many different y
> values.  Which one will you use to sort that x-value in the output?
> ```

It's not very clear what you want (an example?), but if you intend to sort all records by ':order' column, and then remove duplicated values, you can do that first with DISTINCT ON: , and then reorder:

```
 SELECT p FROM  
    ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (p) * from UserProfile ORDER BY p , :order) 
    AS UserProfileUniq 
  ORDER BY :order ;
```

Comment: So what I was doing was something like this:

* Create a named query (which corresponds to the query I posted)
* I set the parameters, including the ':order' parameter which indicated which column I wanted to sort on

My expectation was that my query would get translated to something like:

SELECT DISTINCT p FROM UserProfile p ORDER BY lastLoginDate;

That is the behavior with MySQL.  I'll run the code again with increased logging and post what I get.  I'll also try leonbloy's method.

Someone also recommended removing DISTINCT if I don't need it.  Do you think that will work?

Comment: To understand if it will work, we must understand the result you expect, with some example (with data).