# How to average product review scores using activerecord and POSTGRES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with 100 product reviews. Each review has an "id", "product_id", and "score". Now, what I want to do is present the average score for each product... So is there a way to query the DB using Rails to do this?  I'm sure there must be, but I can't figure it out. I would like the following to occur:

```
Toyota Corolla 70%
Toyota Camry 78%
Toyota Avalon 80%
```

.. obviously based on multiple reviews for each that are averaged, but presented in the above fashion.

UPDATE:

For those interested in the solution

This is in the controller:

```
@ordered_hash = Review.group('aidmodel_id').average('score')
@keys = @ordered_hash.keys
@reviews = Review.where(:aidmodel_id=>@keys).uniq_by {|x| x.aidmodel_id}
```

This is in the view:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>

    <%= review.aidmodel.id %>
    <%= @ordered_hash[review.aidmodel_id] %>

  <% end %>
```

The `@ordered_hash[review.aidmodel_id]` line provides the averaged score for the aidmodel with the desired ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mix [average](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#average) and [group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) to do something like

```
MyClass.group('product_id').average('score')
# => {product_id1 => average1, product_id2 => average2, ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Baldrick. Just one problem for me. Running in Rails console I get the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "reviews.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I simply ran the following in console (where aidmodel_id is equivalent to product_id in my case): Review.group('aidmodel_id').average('score')

Comment: I don't know why you have this error. I've tested on one of my model, it gave me the following SQL request `Match.group('championship_id').average('date')` => `(30.0ms)  SELECT AVG("matches"."date") AS average_date, championship_id AS championship_id FROM "matches" GROUP BY championship_id`

Comment: Ah, yes, this is the problem. Postgres is a bit more strict... There are a few posts on SO related to this issue with Postgres, but the queries are a bit different than mine... so I still can't figure it out. Thanks anyway, I will upvote your answer, but will wait for one relevant to Postgres for the tick =)

Comment: @Abram: That should work fine with PostgreSQL, what exactly are you trying? As an aside, there's also `Model.average(:x, :group => :y)`.

Comment: Mu, I tried this again using your syntax... same error: SELECT AVG("reviews"."score") AS average_score, aidmodel_id AS aidmodel_id FROM "reviews" GROUP BY aidmodel_id ORDER BY reviews.created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "reviews.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @Abram The `ORDER_BY` is the cause the problem. Did you add it manually to the request, or maybe you have a scope that adds it...

Comment: Yes, I forgot I added a default order scope inside of my model. Thanks all good now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the query as

```
MyClass.select('product_id').group('product_id').average('score')
```

have a look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125739/postgres-error-using-group-by-and-order-on-heroku).

Update:

Try `MyClass.select('DISTINCT(product_id)').group('product_id').average('score')`

Look here [group by in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769361/postgresql-group-by-different-from-mysql)

Comment: Unfortunately I am seeing the same error: SELECT AVG("reviews"."score") AS average_score, aidmodel_id AS aidmodel_id FROM "reviews" GROUP BY aidmodel_id ORDER BY reviews.created_at DESC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "reviews.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Your code does work... so I am upvoting it, but Baldrick has been working with me for a while, and he resolved my problem .. it was a default scope in my Review model. Thanks!