# Group by or Select Distinct with Rails, ActiveRecord, Heroku and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a table of records;

Users: id, screen_name, tweet

I want to return a list of the users and group by the screen_name so that there aren't duplicate screen_names in the list.

```
@users = User.all(:group => "screen_name")
```

This works fine when using MySQL, but not when I push to Heroku, which uses PostgreSQL.

**How can I get a similar set of results using PostgreSQL?**

There seem to be a good few posts on this but I couldn't figure out an answer from the comments.

Comment: If you actually want to get (honestly frightening) mysql like group by results in postgres, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769361/postgresql-group-by-different-from-mysql `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a,b,c,d,e FROM table ORDER BY a,b,c`

Comment: Thanks Will. I tried @users = User.all(:select => "DISTINCT ON (screen_name) screen_name, tweet" but the log showed the error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column id_list.alias_0 does not exist"

Answer (score 2):

Unless screen_name is not a primary key you should add all columns in your group statement or aggregate them. But it looks like that you can't aggregate id or tweets ))

```
.group("id, screen_name, tweet")
```

You can also normalize your database. Put screen names to another table and you will be able to get desired data easily.

Comment: I tried adding all fields to the group  @users = User.all(:select => "screen_name,tweet", :group => "screen_name,tweet"  but unfortunately that seems to return all the records (including duplicates of screen_name). Would like to try and avoid normalizing if possible