# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problem with my query, I read some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list) regarding this, but with no luck.

I have 3 tables, Phase, Stage and Schedule.

**Schedule columns:**

*ID, StageId, PhaseId, Duration, ScheduleType*

**Stage columns:**

*StageId, StageName*

**Phase columns:**

*PhaseId, PhaseName*

And here's what I'm trying to get:

```
DECLARE @actual_startdate date = '2014-01-10'
SELECT 
    DISTINCT (C.PhaseName), 
    A.Duration, 
    @actual_startdate StartDate, 
    DATEADD(dd, A.Duration, @actual_startdate) EndDate 
FROM Schedule A
INNER JOIN Stages B
ON A.StageId = B.StageId
INNER JOIN Phase C
ON A.PhaseId = C.PhaseId
WHERE A.Schedule = '2' and B.Stage = '0.25'
ORDERBY B.StageId DESC;
```

And I'm getting this error:

***ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.***

I tried other suggestions as for my research to use **GROUP BY** clause instead of DISTINCT but still with no luck.

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @actual_startdate date = '2014-01-10'
SELECT 
    C.PhaseName, 
    A.Duration, 
    @actual_startdate StartDate, 
    DATEADD(dd, A.Duration, @actual_startdate) EndDate 
FROM Schedule A
INNER JOIN Stages B
ON A.StageId = B.StageId
INNER JOIN Phase C
ON A.PhaseId = C.PhaseId
WHERE A.Schedule = '2' and B.Stage = '0.25'
GROUP BY C.PhaseName
order BY B.StageId DESC;
```

And got new error:

***Column 'Schedule.Duration' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.***

Hope someone can help me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add `A.Duration` in Group By Clause

```
DECLARE @actual_startdate date = '2014-01-10'
SELECT 
    C.PhaseName, 
    A.Duration, 
    @actual_startdate StartDate, 
    DATEADD(dd, A.Duration, @actual_startdate) EndDate 
FROM Schedule A
INNER JOIN Stages B
ON A.StageId = B.StageId
INNER JOIN Phase C
ON A.PhaseId = C.PhaseId
WHERE A.Schedule = '2' and B.Stage = '0.25'
GROUP BY C.PhaseName,A.Duration,B.StageId 
order BY B.StageId DESC;
```

Comment: I also tried this, but got this error 'Column "Stages.StageId" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: fetl so very stupid about that! LOL Thanks a lot!! :) 6 minutes to accept your answer XD