# Rails select distinct and order by most recent

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Notifications modal and a User modal where User has many Notifications and the notifications are sent between users. I need a function to get the newest notification from each user, and return them sorted by their timestamps.

I tried using SELECT DISTINCT .. ORDER BY:

```
@notifications = Notification.select("DISTINCT(notifier_id, created_at)").order('created_at DESC')
```

which generates this SQL: `SELECT DISTINCT(notifier_id, created_at) FROM "notifications"  ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC, created_at DESC)`

but I get the error: `SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

`created_at` does appear in the select list, so what's the problem?

Based on this post: [PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list)

I tried using SELECT ... GROUP BY .. ORDER BY:

```
@notifications = Notification.select("notifier_id").group("notifier_id").order("MAX(created_at)")
```

which generates this SQL: `SELECT "notifications"."notifier_id" FROM "notifications" GROUP BY notifier_id  ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC, MAX(created_at)`

but now I get this error: `column "notifications.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I am using an aggregate function, so what is the error about?

UPDATE:

Using this code:

```
@notifications = Notification.select("DISTINCT ON (created_at) created_at, notifier_id").order('created_at DESC')
```

I get back a list of all messages, instead of just the newest from each sender.

Comment: The error output you are getting basically tells you what to fix.  Have you tried doing that?

Comment: could you explain what the basic solution is?

Comment: Your second `GROUP BY` query is a bit messy.  Could you post some sample data along with what your desired result is?  This is more of a Postgres problem than a Ruby problem.

Comment: Ok I added more info at the bottom. I think I was confused b/c I usually use WHERE queries and they return all the attributes. With SELECT you have to specify which attributes to return or use a * right? If so, how can I work all those other attributes into the DISTINCT query?

Comment: Your distinct query is fine now.  As for the `GROUP BY` query, you can only include columns which are either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or which are aggregates (e.g. `SUM`, `COUNT`) of columns.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@messages = Message.select("DISTINCT ON (created_at) created_at, sender_id").order('created_at DESC')
```

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s).

You will have to rework the second query per the error message.

Comment: that runs Ok but now I get an error related to an attribute not existing when I try to print out the message. Do I have to include every attribute I want to retrieve in both select and group? If so, is there a cleaner way to write this if I have say 12 attributes to retrieve?

Comment: @Cbas In Postgres you must include columns you select in the `GROUP BY` clause _unless_ they appear inside aggregate functions (e.g. `SUM`).  Your error may be a general SQL problem rather than a limitation in my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was able to fix that problem, but now I'm getting back a list of ALL messages, not just the newest from each sender. Is there a way to prevent getting back multiple messages from the same users? I copied and pasted the code into the update

Comment: In order to answer this I am going to need to see sample input and desired output.  You might want to ask a new question since few people will be paying attention to this question now.