# postgres - distinct order_by a jsonb key throws a rails PG::InvalidColumnReference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My user model has the following definition for the `follower` association:

```
has_many :passive_follow_actions, -> { where("actions.activity_verb = 'follow'").uniq }, class_name: 'Action', foreign_key: :activity_object_id
has_many :followers, through: :passive_follow_actions, source: :activity_actor, source_type: 'User'
#
```

User table has a jsonb field called follow_stats which I use to order the follower results.

On its own, a distinct operation works

```
has_many :followers, -> { distinct }, through: :passive_follow_actions, source: :activity_actor, source_type: 'User'
# SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "actions" ON "users"."id" = "actions"."activity_actor_id" WHERE "actions"."activity_object_id" = 1 AND (actions.activity_verb = 'follow') AND "actions"."activity_actor_type" = 'User'
#
```

Also on its own, an order operation works

```
has_many :followers, -> { order("follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC") }, through: :passive_follow_actions, source: :activity_actor, source_type: 'User'
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "actions" ON "users"."id" = "actions"."activity_actor_id" WHERE "actions"."activity_object_id" = 1 AND (actions.activity_verb = 'follow') AND "actions"."activity_actor_type" = 'User' ORDER BY follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC
#
```

However, put together,

```
has_many :followers, -> { distinct.order("follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC") }, through: :passive_follow_actions, source: :activity_actor, source_type: 'User'
# SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "actions" ON "users"."id" = "actions"."activity_actor_id" WHERE "actions"."activity_object_id" = 1 AND (actions.activity_verb = 'follow') AND "actions"."activity_actor_type" = 'User' ORDER BY follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC
#
```

it throws the following exception:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
#
```

I tried adding the jsonb query onto the select clause to prevent the error, but that results in an empty response:

```
has_many :followers, -> { select("follow_stats->'followers_count'").uniq.order("follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC") },  through: :passive_follow_actions, source: :activity_actor, source_type: 'User'
# SELECT DISTINCT follow_stats->'followers_count' FROM "users" INNER JOIN "actions" ON "users"."id" = "actions"."activity_actor_id" WHERE "actions"."activity_object_id" = 1 AND (actions.activity_verb = 'follow') AND "actions"."activity_actor_type" = 'User' ORDER BY follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC
#
```

Response:

```
[#<User id: nil, ?column?: 42>, #<User id: nil, ?column?: 4>, #<User id: nil, ?column?: 2>, #<User id: nil, ?column?: 1>, #<User id: nil, ?column?: 0>]
#
```

When I add a * in the select clause, it returns the same exception PG::InvalidColumnReference

```
has_many :followers, -> { select("*, follow_stats->'followers_count'").uniq.order("follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC") },  through: :passive_follow_actions, source: :activity_actor, source_type: 'User'
#SELECT DISTINCT *, follow_stats->'followers_count' FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"actions\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"actions\".\"activity_actor_id\" WHERE \"actions\".\"activity_object_id\" = 1 AND (actions.activity_verb = 'follow') AND \"actions\".\"activity_actor_type\" = 'User' ORDER BY follow_stats->'followers_count' DESC
#
```

How select distinct and order by a jsonb key at the same time?

Comment: Try to change select as `select("follow_stats->'followers_count', *")`

Comment: Tried that too but got same result as `select("*, follow_stats->'followers_count'")`

Comment: Could you add raw SQL(from rails console or logs)? It allows non-RoR people to be involved.