# [AWS Athena]: How to use DISTINCT with SELECT ALL, and ORDER BY

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, distinct, amazon-athena

I'm using AWS Athena, I have a query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY purchase_date ASC
```

But I want to de-dupe the records.

Since this is Athena, and it needs to process records in parallel, I'm not sure how to write the DISTINCT clause.

How can I make this query so that it doesn't have any duplicate records in the result set?

Thanks

Comment: just use `select distinct c1,c2...from tbl`

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala that doesn't work because the nature of AWS Athena is such that it's streaming records and becuase I have an ORDER BY clause, it somehow needs all the records... anyway let me try what you're saying thank you very much

Comment: that implementation detail you shouldn't worry about

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala so I did SELECT DISTINCT foo, bar from tbl but I got only the columns foo and bar in the result set.  How to get all columns?

Comment: This seems to work:
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *, 
      row_number() over (partition by foo) as row_number
FROM tbl
      ) AS ROWS
WHERE row_number = 1
order by bar

which I got from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list