# Ruby on Rails - order not working with distinct.pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

**app/model/line_item.rb**

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { order(:order_date, :line_item_index) }
  scope :sorted, -> { order(:order_date, :line_item_index) }
  scope :open_order_names, -> { distinct.pluck(:order_name) }
end
```

What I have tried:

```
LineItem.open_order_names        # Way 1
LineItem.sorted.open_order_names # Way 2
LineItem.open_order_names.sorted # Way 3
```

But I am always getting this error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ne_items"."order_name" FROM "line_items" ORDER BY "line_item...
                                                                 ^
):
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list)

Comment: @JakeWorth, it didn't help me.

Comment: Sorry to hear! It's definitely a database, not Ruby, issue. To summarize what that post and others seem to be saying: if you collapse your results down to only distinct `order_name`s, when there is a duplicate `order_name`, from which record should the `order_date` or `line_item_index` be chosen for the ordering? Postgres can't decide.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you need to specify how they should be distinct, the following should work for you, the select may not be needed.

`scope :open_order_names, -> { select(:order_name).distinct(:order_name).pluck(:order_name) }`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but *LineItem.open_order_names.sorted* doesn't work after I have updated that scope.

Comment: Yea it's the `select`, see if you can remove it, if you can't, may may need to be more specific with what columns you pull from the database. Though slight chance `select(:*)` works, but that should be what the default (without select) is so kind of doubt it.

Comment: Another option is to just add a unique field that you can use instead to avoid the need for a distinct using a where or join where the combination is unique works well, that's usually how I do it. I try to avoid using distinct as much as possible precisely because of this, it get's messy.

Answer (score 0):

So it's database restriction. For example we have users table with (id, email).
You can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "users"."email" FROM "users"
```

or

```
SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC
```

but can not:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "users"."email" FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC
```

i.e. you can not order by column which abcent in the SELECT part of query if you use the DISTINCT.

As mentioned above the

```
scope :open_order_names, -> { select(:order_name).distinct(:order_name).pluck(:order_name) }
```

could be nice solution.