# Hibernate @Formula lazy-loading for JPA Sort

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have Entity with `@Formula` field, which contains select expression. Then I refer to this field as Hibernate meta-model's string attribute and use it in `Sort.by()` and therefore in `PageRequest.of()` methods. It works just fine until I add `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)`, after that I get `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list` with `o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P10`.

What exactly I'm doing wrong?

P. S. I've turned on hibernate-enhance with `enableLazyInitialization = true` (otherwise lazy-loading for @Formula field won't work, as much as I know)

Field code looks like this:

```java
    @Formula("(SELECT st.fio " +
            "FROM conjunction_table ct " +
            "JOIN second_table st ON st.id = ct.second_table_id " +
            "WHERE ct.first_table_id = id " +
            "ORDER BY st.fio " +
            "LIMIT 1)")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private String secondTableFio;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lazy fetching does not include the computed property in your `SELECT DISTINCT` clause, which then causes this error, since there is now a property in the `ORDER BY` clause, which is not selected.

This is restricted by postgres because the `DISTINCT` could remove duplicate rows from the result which may actually have different `ORDER BY` values, so that the decision on how to order the selected rows cannot be made:
[PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list)