# TypeORM selecting N random rows from table

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to select a certain number of Questions from my postgres database using TypeORM 0.3.11 with NestJS.
I tried using the createQueryBuilder to create that specific SQL query, but I keep getting the exception: "for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list".

So, I wrote next method, which should (by my interpretation) select rows that have corresponding quiz ID, load answers, "shuffle" questions and take only N questions (20 in this example).

```
  async findByQuizAndServeRandomlyQuery(quiz: Quiz): Promise<Question[]> {
    const questions = await this.questionRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .setFindOptions({
        where: {
          quiz: {
            id: quiz.id,
          },
        },
        relations: {
          answers: true,
        },
      })
      .orderBy('RANDOM()')
      .take(20)
      .getMany();

    return questions;
  }
```

I checked, the quiz variable is defined, RANDOM() is available in postgres.

When the method is called, next exception is thrown:

QueryFailedError: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

I'm not sure why DISTINCT is included here.

[EDIT] Here is my question entity schema:

```
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Quiz } from './quiz.entity';

@Entity('quiz-questions')
export class Question {
  constructor(partial?: Partial<Question>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);

    if (!this.positivePoints) this.positivePoints = 1;
    if (!this.negativePoints) this.negativePoints = 0;
  }

  @Expose()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Exclude()
  @ManyToOne(() => Quiz, (quiz) => quiz.questions)
  @JoinColumn()
  quiz: Quiz;

  @Expose()
  @Column()
  text: string;

  @Expose()
  @Column({ default: 1 })
  positivePoints: number;

  @Expose()
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  negativePoints: number;
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693353/) *might* help.  Can you post your DB schema? Do your questions have their primary keys set? What happens if you try the same query in PostgreSQL (directly, as if you were entering a query through PG admin, or any other DB software)?

Comment: Hi, I posted the schema. I tried the query that TypeORM gives out with getSql(). It does not include the 'take' keyword. When I enter the quiz ID, and execute the query, it give me all the anwsers for the question.