# ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My requirement is to get distinct records and in order

```
User.joins('INNER JOIN report_posts ON posts.id = report_posts.post_id').select('DISTINCT ON (report_posts.post_id) posts.id as report_posts.id as reported_id, report_posts.reported_at').order('report_posts.reported_at desc')
```

I know this is not possible in `postgresql`, I already read this [Postgresql DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by)

I want its solution that how can I do do this, its alternate way?

Comment: Use GROUP BY on all columns to get distinct values.

Comment: @Pholochtairze that's not correct, DISTINCT is the right statement to use. MySQL implements grouping incorrectly, which is probably what causes the confusion. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1777448/1087866

Answer (score 10):

You need to include the DISTINCT column in your order:

```
.order('report_posts.post_id, report_posts.reported_at desc')
```

Comment: what if I added a `CASE ... AS some_field` to Select section and I'm going to distinct on it? 
I placed `some_field` to `distinct on` as well as to `select` and `order by` but got the same error