# Group by issue in postgresql

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate

we have upgraded `mysql`  to `postgres9.6` recently. and found below issues with the criteria code.
This is my code

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getBotInstanceWiseMetricsByUserAccess(Integer userId, List<Integer> projectIds, Integer botId) {
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> botMetricsForUser = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        try{
            Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(BotExecutionDetails.class, "botExecution");
            if(projectIds != null && projectIds.size() > 0){

                criteria.createAlias("botExecution.botId", "botMaster");
                criteria.createAlias("botExecution.projectId", "projectMaster");
                criteria.createAlias("botExecution.botDownloadDetails", "downloadInstance");

                criteria.add(Restrictions.in("projectMaster.id", projectIds));
                if(botId != null && botId > 0){
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("botMaster.id", botId));
                }

                ProjectionList p1=Projections.projectionList();
                p1 = Projections.projectionList();

                p1.add(Projections.property("botMaster.id"));
                p1.add(Projections.property("botMaster.botName"));
                p1.add(Projections.property("botExecution.botInstanceId"));
                p1.add(Projections.property("projectMaster.id"));
                p1.add(Projections.property("projectMaster.projectName"));
                p1.add(Projections.property("projectMaster.projectCode"));
                p1.add(Projections.count("downloadInstance.instanceDetailId"));
                p1.add(Projections.sum("botExecution.numberOfTransaction"));    
                p1.add(Projections.sum("botExecution.costSaved"));  
                p1.add(Projections.sum("botExecution.effortSaved"));
                p1.add(Projections.sum("botExecution.timeSaved"));  

                p1.add(Projections.groupProperty("botExecution.botInstanceId"));
                criteria.setProjection(p1);     

                List<Object[]> botMetricsDetails = criteria.list();

                if(botMetricsDetails != null && botMetricsDetails.size() > 0){
                    for(Object[] botMetricDetail : botMetricsDetails){
                        HashMap<String, Object> botMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        botMetrics.put("botId", (Integer)botMetricDetail[0]);
                        botMetrics.put("botName", (String)botMetricDetail[1]);
                        botMetrics.put("botInstanceId", (String)botMetricDetail[2]);
                        botMetrics.put("projectId", (Integer)botMetricDetail[3]);
                        botMetrics.put("projectName", (String)botMetricDetail[4]);
                        botMetrics.put("projectCode", (String)botMetricDetail[5]);
                        botMetrics.put("noOfExecution", (Long)botMetricDetail[6]);
                        botMetrics.put("noOfTransaction", (Long)botMetricDetail[7]);
                        botMetrics.put("costSaved", (Double)botMetricDetail[8]);
                        botMetrics.put("effortSaved", BigDecimal.valueOf((Double)botMetricDetail[9] / 60).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
                        botMetrics.put("timeSaved", BigDecimal.valueOf((Double)botMetricDetail[10] / 60).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
                        botMetricsForUser.add(botMetrics);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            botMetricsForUser = null;
            log.error("Error in getBotInstanceWiseMetricsByUserAccess - ", ex);
        }
        return botMetricsForUser;
    }
```

and the errors i am getting:

> 2017-11-14 12:48:23 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - ERROR: column
>   "botmaster1_.botid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in
>   an aggregate function   Position: 8 2017-11-14 12:48:23 ERROR
>   ProjectAndOrganisationLevelDAOImpl:840 - Error in
>   getBotInstanceWiseMetricsByUserAccess - 
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)   at
>   com.hcl.ers.bots.platform.dao.impl.ProjectAndOrganisationLevelDAOImpl.getBotInstanceWiseMetricsByUserAccess(ProjectAndOrganisationLevelDAOImpl.java:818)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.getBotInstanceWiseMetricsByUserAccess(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.hcl.ers.bots.platform.service.impl.ProjectAndOrganisationLevelServiceImpl.getBotMetricsForTypeByUserAccess(ProjectAndOrganisationLevelServiceImpl.java:645)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.getBotMetricsForTypeByUserAccess(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.hcl.ers.bots.platform.controller.ProjectAndOrganisationLevelManagementController.getBotMetricsForTypeByUserAccess(ProjectAndOrganisationLevelManagementController.java:733)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:174)
>     at
>   com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "botmaster1_.botid"
>   must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   Position: 8   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)    at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
>     ... 107 more 2017-11-14 12:48:23 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:145 - SQL
>   Error: 0, SQLState: 42803 2017-11-14 12:48:23 ERROR
>   SqlExceptionHelper:147 - ERROR: column "organisati3_.id" must appear
>   in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function   Position:
>   60 2017-11-14 12:48:23 ERROR ProjectAndOrganisationLevelDAOImpl:778 -
>   Error in getRuntimeWiseBotMetricsByUserAccess - 
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)   at
>   com.hcl.ers.bots.platform.dao.impl.ProjectAndOrganisationLevelDAOImpl.getRuntimeWiseBotMetricsByUserAccess(ProjectAndOrganisationLevelDAOImpl.java:751)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.getRuntimeWiseBotMetricsByUserAccess(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.hcl.ers.bots.platform.service.impl.ProjectAndOrganisationLevelServiceImpl.getBotMetricsForTypeByUserAccess(ProjectAndOrganisationLevelServiceImpl.java:643)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.getBotMetricsForTypeByUserAccess(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.hcl.ers.bots.platform.controller.ProjectAndOrganisationLevelManagementController.getBotMetricsForTypeByUserAccess(ProjectAndOrganisationLevelManagementController.java:733)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:174)
>     at
>   com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "organisati3_.id"
>   must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   Position: 60  at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)

Comment: This is an SQL error: `ERROR: column "botmaster1_.botid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. So you have column in select list which is not in group by clause - PostgreSQL is more SQL compilant than MySQL, for answer see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769361/postgresql-group-by-different-from-mysql

Comment: Thanks for your reply!..

Comment: But If I add in groupby,the data is not coming properly. Need a solution for that